# Reusing visual tree when moving items between two ItemControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, itemscontrol

I have two `ObservableCollection`s in my ViewModel. Both of same generic type.
Window has two `ItemsControl`s each with `ItemsSource` bound on its own `ObservableCollection` from ViewModel.
Both use same same `ItemTemplate`. This `ItemTemplate` is very complex user control.
It's all done by the book.

In some cases, I move item from one collection to another. UI updates correctly. However, as control is complex, it needs about 1-2sec to render when it is recreated in new `ItemsControl`. And since this happens on drag and drop operation, it is not user friendly.

What I would like to do is to somehow preserve existing instance of `ItemTemplate` from source `ItemsControl` and reuse it in destination. I don't know if it is even possible, I couldn't find anything about it online.

I believe setup is fairly simple, but if needed I'll write some simplified version of code (I can't share the real code).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I fear you will have to work with controls directly (so, not binding ItemsControl.ItemsSource but adding controls directly to ItemsControl.Items) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is to somehow preserve existing instance of ItemTemplate from source ItemsControl and reuse it in destination. I don't know if it is even possible, I couldn't find anything about it online.

I am afraid it is not. When you disconnect an element from the visual tree and then add it back to a different parent element at a later stage, all elements that make up the control will be re-rendered.

Comment: They will be rerendered, but not recreated, which might make huge perfomance difference.

Comment: The control won't be re-created, i.e. its constructor won't be invoked again, but it will still be re-rendered - its Loaded event will fire again - and it is (probably) this rendering of the child elements that takes 1-2 seconds.

Comment: I don't know if rendering is taking more time or instantiating but saving time for either would be at least some improvement.
Also, I have a feeling that creating instances of all controls (in that user control) and bindings  take up most of the time.

Comment: The visual tree of your control will be re-created when you re-attach it to another parent element and then the data bindings will be evaluated again.